# Navigating to a new page from a viewmodel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have used the WP7 DataBound app template for my program which utilises a form of MVVM. I would like to navigate from my mainpage to my settings page but since it is the VM that loads the data, which in turn determines if the settings pages needs to be loaded, I should like to call navigate code from the VM, not the view. However, NavigationService does not show the Navigate method in the VM, only in the view.  Does anyone have any suggesions about how I can/should call the Navigate method in the VM?

Thanks,

Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement it as a static method in your `App.xaml.cs`, like this

```
public static void Navigate(Uri source)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => (App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(source));
}
```

That way you can simply call `App.Navigate(uri)` from anywhere.

You might also want to implement `GoBack()`:

```
public static void GoBack()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => (App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).GoBack());
}
```

Comment: that is more or less a kind of ServiceLocator, if you see the static application-class as the Locator and the implementation itself ;)

Answer (score 1):

i tend to use one of the following

- publish a event in the VM, subscribe in the view
- implement a global NavigationService (using the ServiceLocator pattern or DI), you can for example implement such a Interface in your application-class

Comment: Do you have any useful examples or resources that explain a ServiceLocator pattern?

Comment: Why overcomplicate it so much. If you really wanted pure separation, then navigation should remain a task for the View only.

Comment: Claus, the data that determines if the page should be navigated to is in the VM, as is the event handler for loading the data and as such this seems like the right place to perform the navigation. I have implement the event you suggested and it works well, however, the state method in the app.xaml.cs seems like it might be more useful to be able to jump from VM to V without a bunch of events and handlers everywhere.  Many thanks for your solution.